# What information do I need for initial setup of BGP?

Tags: router, datacenter, bgp, protocols, mikrotik

I will be installing a MikroTik BGP capable router into a datacentre tomorrow, I have almost no idea how to do this but luckily there is an identical mikrotik router that has already been setup and is sitting next to it on a different connection :)

So, I have been searching around for a long time and haven't been able to draw any definite conclusions, what information do I need from the datacentre provider to get the BGP working? (peers, ip addresses, etc) I know there is a lot that is populated automatically, so it is hard to tell what has been manually entered and what was automatically done.

Your help on this is appreciated guys, as long as i know what information I have to put into the router I should be able to find where it goes in and cross my fingers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about BGP with the Internet world ?
If it's the case you will first need an [Autonomous system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) number then might chang routers if you want a BGP full view as MikroTik seems to [not be able to handle that very well](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=31213) without a a high configuration.
You need your own IP block to be announce as well as your provider BGP peer IP.

But what you really need is to read a book about BGP. Oops I said need, I meant **MUST**.
BGP is complex and you have to understand it very very well before using it too peer with someone else.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that the BGP first hits some kind of private network and that in turn goes out to the internet. 

Luckily I got some help and I have figured it out. I just need the AS number and details of peers. 

I've read through the cisco CCNA books on hand but they have NO info at all on BGP. 

Well they do, but its mostly stuff I knew already. 
Any good resource of information you could recommend?

Comment: The O'Reilly BGP book is reasonably good.